# Apply a function to a file if it exists

Tags: haskell

I have a function that apply a function to a file if it exists:

```
import System.Directory
import Data.Maybe

applyToFile :: (FilePath -> IO a) -> FilePath -> IO (Maybe a)
applyToFile f p = doesFileExist p >>= apply
  where 
    apply True  = f p >>= (pure . Just)
    apply False = pure Nothing
```

Usage example:

```
applyToFile readFile "/tmp/foo"
applyToFile (\p -> writeFile p "bar") "/tmp/foo"
```

A level of abstraction can be added with:

```
import System.Directory
import Data.Maybe

applyToFileIf :: (FilePath -> IO Bool) -> (FilePath -> IO a) ->  FilePath -> IO (Maybe a)
applyToFileIf f g p = f p >>= apply
  where 
    apply True  = g p >>= (pure . Just)
    apply False = pure Nothing

applyToFile :: (FilePath -> IO a) -> FilePath -> IO (Maybe a)
applyToFile f p = applyToFileIf doesFileExist f p
```

That allow usages like:

```
applyToFileIf (\p -> doesFileExist p >>= (pure . not)) (\p -> writeFile p "baz") "/tmp/baz"
```

I have the feeling that I just scratched the surface and there is a more generic pattern hiding.
Are there better abstractions or more idiomatic ways to do this?

Comment: This question probably belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The bigger problem is that "do something to a file if it exists" is an invitation to race conditions and security holes. The correct approach is almost always to do something to the file and catch the exception that is thrown if it doesn't already exist. This is true regardless of programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`applyToFileIf` can be given a more generic type and a more generic name

```
applyToIf :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m (Maybe b)
applyToIf f g p = f p >>= apply
  where 
    apply True  = g p >>= (return . Just)
    apply False = return Nothing
```

In the type of `applyToIf` we see the composition of two Monads

```
                                           Maybe is a monad ---v 
applyToIf :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m (Maybe b)
                   ^------------- m is a monad -------------^
```

When we see the composition of two monads, we can expect that it could be replaced with a monad transformer stack and some class describing what that monad transformer adds. The [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:MaybeT) transformer replaces `m (Maybe a)`

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

And adds `MonadPlus` to what an `m` can do.

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadPlus (MaybeT m) where ...
```

We'll change the type of `applyToIf` to not have a composition of two monads and instead have a `MonadPlus` constraint on a single monad

```
import Control.Monad

applyToIf :: MonadPlus m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m b
applyToIf f g p = f p >>= apply
  where 
    apply True  = g p
    apply False = mzero
```

This could be rewritten in terms of [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) from `Control.Monad` and given a more generic name.

```
guardBy :: MonadPlus m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m b
guardBy f g p = f p >>= apply
  where 
    apply b = guard b >> g p
```

The second `g` argument adds nothing to what `guardBy` can do. `guardBy f g p` can be replaced by `guardBy f return p >>= g`. We will drop the second argument.

```
guardBy :: MonadPlus m => (a -> m Bool) -> a -> m a
guardBy f p = f p >>= \b -> guard b >> return p
```

The `MaybeT` transformer adds possible failure to any computation. We can use it to recreate `applyToIf` or use it more generally to handle failure through complete programs.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

applyToIf ::  Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m (Maybe b)
applyToIf f g = runMaybeT . (>>= lift . g) . guardBy (lift . f)
```

If you instead rework the program to use monad style classes, it might include a snippet like

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

(MonadPlus m, MonadIO m) =>
    ...
    guardBy (liftIO . doesFileExist) filename >>= liftIO . readFile
```